# Word VBA: Add textboxes with in-line text wrapping to end of document

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word, word-2013

I'm trying to write a macro which will insert textboxes in a Word document, and format them with in-line-with-text text wrapping.

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim newTextbox As Shape
    For I = 1 To 10
        Set newTextbox = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox _
        (Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=50)
        newTextbox.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapInline
        newTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange = I
    Next
End Sub
```

The issue I'm having is that instead of each textbox being added to the start of document, as is currently happening, I need it to be added to the end. I understand that in the example I've given, I could simply use `For I = 10 To 1 Step -1`. However, due to my use of the textboxes in the actual project I'm working on, this is not possible.

I have spent a few hours playing with the code but just haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Josh.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua, here is a final working code:

```
Sub InsertInlineTextBox()

' Move all the text after the cursor to a new paragraph
' and jump to the start point of this paragraph
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, count:=1

Dim aShape As Shape

' Insert the shape at the current cursor position +1 point down in vertical
' direction to prevent automatic moving the shape to the previous paragraph
' during 'inlining'
Set aShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage), _
    Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) + 1, 400, 60)

With aShape
    .TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0 ' adjust text margins
    .TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0
    .TextFrame.MarginRight = 0
    .TextFrame.MarginTop = 0
    .Line.Visible = msoFalse    ' don't show the border

    ' converting to InlineShape will place
    ' the shape at the start point of paragraph
    .ConvertToInlineShape
End With

' Remove carriege return before the shape
Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdParagraph, Extend:=wdMove
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
End Sub
```

I also use this macro to disable spell check in the textboxes 
because usually they contain a bunch of C++ example code:

```
Sub NoSpellCheck()
  Selection.Range.SpellingChecked = True
  Selection.Range.NoProofing = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm guessing you're not on Word 2013? I actually asked this question on [another forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-customize/vba-add-textboxes-with-in-line-text-wrapping-to/42b4ebc5-6dde-4a5f-b4db-48e1ab0b8aa0) and got a few suggestions from people there, which all worked on their copy of Word 2010 but not my 2013. Would you please confirm this is the case (i.e. your code works for you in an earlier version of word)?

Comment: Joshua, I updated the code today after some morning insights)). Yes, this is developed for Word 2013, but Shape and InlineShape objects are available in 2010 version as well.

Comment: Hehm, I still can't seem to get this working. I've added the following code to get the numbers typed in to the textboxes (as per original question):
`For I = 1 To 10` after the Sub statement,
`.TextFrame.TextRange = I` after the With statement,
`Next` after the End Sub statement,
And yet I still have the problem where the most top-left textbox is 10 rather than 1. If this is working for you in 2013, might I ask what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Inlining always puts the textbox at the start of current line, therefore you need always create new paragraph for each textbox to isolate it from the other text before any other manipulations, so I think you may:
1) create paragraph
2) insert textbox in this paragraph (AddTextbox, ConvertToInlineShape)
3) create a new paragraph just after the textbox and insert new textbox
Repeate this procedure 10 times.
After that move to the end of each newly created paragraph end remove carriege return (the last 3 code lines). You should finally get 10 textboxes ordered as desired.